# Google Contacts API v3 - How to update gender using C#.net?

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Contacts API v3, I'm unable to update gender information for a contact

```
public static Contact UpdateContactName(ContactsRequest cr, Uri contactURL) 
{ 
  // First, retrieve the contact to update. 
  Contact contact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(contactURL); 
  contact.Name.FullName = "New Name"; 
  contact.Name.GivenName = "New"; 
  contact.Name.FamilyName = "Name"; 
  contact.ContactEntry.AddExtension(new Gender("male"));
  try 
  { 
    Contact updatedContact = cr.Update(contact); 
    Console.WriteLine("Updated: " + updatedEntry.Updated.ToString()) 
    return updatedContact; 
  } 
  catch (GDataVersionConflictException e) 
  { 
    // Etags mismatch: handle the exception. 
  } 
  return null; 
}
```

Comment: What issues are you having? Is it throwing an exception? Does it run and just not update?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?